# Power supply to power a raw SATA disk (HIGH-QUALITY supply!)

Tags: power-supply, sata

I'm looking for an external power supply to power raw SATA disks. The catch is I want a **high quality, well-built** supply.

There's plenty of supplies on Amazon, eBay, etc. that convert AC power to a 4-pin Molex which can then be easily converted to SATA power. The problem is that it seems that almost all of these are cheap bottom-barrel (Chinese) supplies that feel like a cheap plastic toy. I took a chance and ordered two different ones from Amazon and both times they were so frail and got EXTREMELY hot (enough to make the melting-hot-plastic smell eminate into the room) from running a standard SATA drive - these things seemed like fire hazards!! I'm not willing to risk this again until I can find a supply which is from a reputable electronics manufacturer...

I've purchased external enclosures in the past which come with very high quality, well built supplies that feel rock solid and run cool and smooth. They clearly output +5/+12 on a 4-pin mini-DIN. I want a supply like that but with a Molex end (which is easily converted to SATA). I'm not a solderer or anything so finding and modifying one of these isn't an option right now.

Obviously I'm willing to pay a reasonable premium for a quality supply. You do get what you pay for - the Amazon supplies I tried were all $10 and under, but going above that, you start getting into full ATX PSU territory and weeding out actual supplies like

Comment: What's wrong with an actual ATX PSU?  Also, add how many drives you're trying to power to the question.

Comment: Same question as @BryanBoettcher. Seems like the correct solution.